# How to keep displays "set" and not vanishing when screenblanking or turned off?

Tags: x11, display-settings

I have thee screens and am finding it very annoying and distracting to find (1) my X settings have changed to make the leftmost Primary and not aligned right, and (2) all the windows moved onto the left screen with their sizes shrunk down too.  This causes a similar effect in my full-screes virtual machines.

This is a desktop workstation, not a laptop subject to docking and presentation projectors.  Turning off a display ***does not mean it is removed***.  Blanking a screen after inactivity having that effect is just wrong.

Can I be heavy-handed somehow and just disable the dynamics? **Don't Change**, period.

---

Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca x64, Cinnamon, Nvidia graphics.  2 monitors on displayport, leftmost on DVI.